# What is the difference between 判{わか}る and 分{わ}かる?

Tags: meaning, kanji, verbs

Until now, I though the only verb for "to know" was 分かる. I saw the verb 判る used for the same meaning today.

> 判{わか}ってるから言{い}ったんだけどね。
>   I knew that. That's why I said it.
>   (*[source](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Imperishable_Night/Story/Scarlet_Team%27s_Scenario)*)

It has the same reading and verb conjugation, but is written with a different Kanji. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Being written with two different kanji doesn't necessarily mean they're two different words.